# Feature Request: may we use notation (markdown language) for headings (header) `# Header #` to enlargen in-line text?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

When I write `##` in the middle of a paragraph, it does not appear large, like a header does.

> middle of ## a line

I wanted to ask the following question, but there was a problem.

> Consider the following clause (partial sentence):
>
> > for any lemon or grape or apple or cherry
>
> What is an example of an atomic table showing the relationship between the following three languages:
>
> 1. Russian
> 2. English
> 3. Emojit Emoticons (such as )
>
> By "Atomic", we mean that strings of text are as short as possible such that there is a bijective one-to-one correspondence between strings of text codified in **English** and strings of text codified in **русский язык**.
>
> The Emojit Emoticons may be used only for nouns if you like.
>
> The decision is at your discretion.
>
> It is **not necessary** (not □) that we use Emojit Emoticons for non-nouns.
>
> We are **allowed** (◊) to use Emojit Emoticons for words other than nouns.

| ∀ | ## | ∨ | ## | ∨ | ## | ∨ | ## |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FOR ANY | LEMON | or | GRAPE | or | APPLE | or | CHERRY |
|  | лимон |  | виноград |  | яблоко |  |  |

However, I cannot make the emojis (emoticons) large enough for people to see very well.

Can we make in-line text larger than usual (possibly the same size as headers) if the text is wrapped in `#` and there are no spaces?

| Type of Header | Regular Expression |
| --- | --- |
| `# Level One #` | `/(?:^\s*)(#\s*[^\n\r]+\s*#*)(?:$)/gm` |
| `## Level Two ##` | `/(?:^\s*)(##\s*[^\n\r]+\s*#*)(?:$)/gm` |
| `### Level Three ###` | `/(?:^\s*)(###\s*[^\n\r]+\s*#*)(?:$)/gm` |
| `in line mid paragraph #bigtext# in the middle of a line#` | ? |

I tried the following regular expression, but it does not work:

```
(?:[^#\r\n]+)(#[^#\r\n\t\f\v ]+#)(?:[^\r\n]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a limited set of HTML tags in markdown:

| ## Big Header | Regular header |
| --- | --- |
| Content | another content |

That said, feature requests for markdown improvements belong on https://meta.stackexchange.com